# How to span the heading of a table to span across the columns in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I need my html5 heading to span across the columns.
So the table should end on the far right with the vertical line appearing at the right end of the table.

Any help would be appreciated !

Here is the jsfiddle and the HTML/CSS is below :-

https://jsfiddle.net/v1f49gkj/

```
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
            }

            table{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width:40%;
            }

            th,td{
                padding:0.25rem;
                text-align: left;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
            }

            tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
                background: #eee;
            }
            </style>
        </head>

            <body>
                <table>
                    <thead><th>Purchaser's Information</th></thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Purchaser's Name : <?php //echo $purchaserName; ?></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Purchaser's Address : <?php// echo $purchaserAddress; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>City/Town : <?php //echo $purchaserCity; ?> </td>
                            <td>Province : <?php //echo $purchaserProvince; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Postal Code : <?php// echo $purchaserPostalCode; ?></td>
                            <td>Home Tel No : <?php// echo $purchaserHomePhone; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Business Tel : <?php// echo $purchaserBTel; ?></td>
                            <td>Email : <?php// echo $purchaserEmail; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Driver License : <?php// echo $purchaserLicense; ?></td>
                            <td>Expiry Date : <?php// echo $purchaserExpiry; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>


                </table>

            </body>
```

Comment: `<thead><th>Purchaser's Information</th></thead>` Aren't you missing something here?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can you point me out as to what I am missing, that would be very helpful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use colspan if you know the maximum colums of your table like:
`<th colspan=2>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use colspan="n" attribute in you th or td element

```
<th colspan="3">
<td colspan="3">
```